# Running application from a different directory

Tags: debian, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I currently have Redmine setup in /usr/share/redmine and I would like to keep /usr read only. I want to be able to run the application out of /srv/redmine. I am using the debian package. The location where the redmine source is located, /usr/share/redmine, must be mounted readonly. I am looking for a way to run it from /srv if possible with chroot but it does not have to be. This is on a debian system. Can anyone provide me with some guidance about how to do this?

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the official package then everything under `/usr` should already be read-only and all the data should be re-directed to /var, or some other user-defined location.  If the package is trying to write under `/usr`, then you should submit a big against that package.

I am not particularly familiar with Redmine, but since it is a web-app, it probably should be very easy to simply copy the source into whatever directory you like, then modify any bits that refer to an absolute path.  Keep in mind, that if you do this, you will have patch or re-copy the files, if or when a update is released.

Comment: Isn't there a way to run the application code from another location without having to copy all the code to the new location?

Comment: @gsieranski, yes, I understand that you want it read-only, but everything under `/usr` should already support being read-only.  If it doesn't already work, then the package is buggy, and violating the FHS requirements.